# A ruby test for nil throws an error

Tags: ruby, comparison, null

1. **x is an Array.**
2. **Notice the two comparisons below**. The first should produce "true", as expected. The second throws an error. What is going on here?

Why does negative comparison for nil not produce false in the **second test**?

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :079 > x[2]['comments']['data'][0]['from']['name'] != nil
 => true 

x[2]['comments']['data'][1]['from']['name'] != nil
NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
    from (irb):78
    from /Users/justinz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /Users/justinz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/justinz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: how does your array look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess it's because the value `x[2]['comments']['data'][1]` is nil.

You might want to use this helper method instead:

```
def nullsafe_index(a, keys)
    keys.each{|key|
        return nil if a.nil?
        a = a[key]
    }
    return a
end
```

Use like this:

```
nullsafe_index(x, [2, 'comments', 'data', 0, 'from', 'name']).nil?
```

Answer (score 1):

x[2]['comments']['data'][1] is an empty hash, so when you call ['from'] on it, the result is nil, which means calling ['name'] on that result of nil, produces an error. Here's how you can reproduce it:

```
x = {}
x['from'] #=> nil
x['from']['name'] #=> NoMethodError
```

You can think of your request as a collection of function calls:

```
x[2]['comments']['data'][1]['from']['name']
# is equivalent to:
x.[](2).[]('comments').[]('data').[](1).[]('from').[]('name')
```

If any one of these function calls returns nil you can't make another [] function call on it without getting an error.

Comment: is there a way to test for a NoMethodError?

Comment: Yes, you can capture it with the begin-raise-end block. You can also assert that an error is raised in test-unit and you can expect an error in rspec.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `x[2]['comments']['data']` doesn't have a second element.  This is equivalent to calling `nil['from']`, which will also raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Is `x[2]['comments']['data'][1] == nil`?

Try evaluating each piece of your expression:

```
x[2]
x[2]['comments']
x[2]['comments']['data']
x[2]['comments']['data'][1]
x[2]['comments']['data'][1]['from']
x[2]['comments']['data'][1]['from']['name']
```